# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Total' not found

Tags: r

I used this is the code to add the percenatage row at the end:

```
adde_percent <- lapply(added_total, function(x){
last_row <- nrow(x)
pct <- Total / sum(Total)
x[last_row+1,] <- c("percentage", pct)
x
})
```

---

I have a list of data frames and want to add the percentage at the end of each data frame in a list. I already added the total. This is a screenshot of a data frame:
[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to subset those rows? `subset(X, PERSNUM == RELAT)` ?

Comment: df$PERSNUM[which(df$PERSNUM == df$RELAT)]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try a simple subset:

```
df[df$PERSNUM == df$RELAT, ]

  PROVINCE PERSNUM RELAT
2       11       1     1
3       11       1     1
4       11       1     1
6       11       1     1
```